# How to intercept Promises response in then or catch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

I am trying to intercept the response from all Promises then method. But i am not able to get the response data in the prototype then method. please find below code.

```
(function(Promise) {
   var originalThen = Promise.prototype.then;
   var originalCatch = Promise.prototype.catch;
   Promise.prototype.then = function() {
      console.log(this, arguments);
      return originalThen.apply(this, arguments);
   };
   Promise.prototype.catch = function() {
      return originalCatch.apply(this, arguments);
   };
})(this.Promise)
```

In the above code I can see the console printed in all Promise call. But i cannot get the response object in the then.

**The Printed 'this' object value in console:**

[image]

**The printed arguments inside the 'then' prototype method:**

[image]

Please suggest me to get the response object in then method for all promises method.

I tried to get the value using "arguments[0].arguments" (Response object in the then callback).But its throwing the below error

> Uncaught TypeError: 'caller' and 'arguments' are restricted function
>   properties and cannot be accessed in this context.

Please suggest me the solution to intercept the response object.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you be up for elaborating on why?

Answer (score 3):

`then` is a synchronous method that registers success and failure callbacks. It returns immediately.

To intercept a future value, insert yourself in place of the success callback:

```js
(function(Promise) {
   var originalThen = Promise.prototype.then;
   Promise.prototype.then = function(onFulfilled, onFailure) {
      return originalThen.call(this, function(value) {
        console.log(value);
        return onFulfilled(value);
      }, onFailure);
   };
})(this.Promise);

Promise.resolve(3).then(() => console.log("Done"));
```

Answer (score 2):

`then()` is called when consuming a promise to add a callback, before the promise actually has a value.
Its arguments are the success and error callbacks.

To see the promise's value, you need to actually call `then()` and pass a callback to see its eventual value.  (or wrap the callbacks you were passed and pass your wrappers to the real `then()`)